# Flutter: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using the following flutter code to display an image a post title and a description ane after another.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LatestPost extends StatelessWidget {
  const LatestPost({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Column(
                children: [
                    SizedBox(
                        width: 70.0,
                        height: 20.0,
                        child: Image.asset("images/image_2.jpg")),
                  const Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                    "Post Title",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

But the following error is thrown:

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.

If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html

This is the design I'm aiming for:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code add `shrinkWrap: true` and remove `Expanded`

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: 5,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 70.0,
              height: 20.0,
              child: Image.network(
                  "https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png"),
            ),
            Text(
              "Post Title",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Result Screen -> [image]

## Answer Update:

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Image.network(
          'https://4.imimg.com/data4/SJ/BA/MY-3018414/apple-laptop-500x500.jpg',
          height: 200,
          width: 300,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Divider(
          color: Colors.black,
          thickness: 1,
        ),
        Text(
          'How Apple\'s M1 chips make macOS developement much less costly',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Divider(
          color: Colors.black,
          thickness: 1,
        ),
        Text(
            'Apple in November 2020 released the first Macs with an Arm-based'
            ' M1 chip, debuting 2020 13-inch MacBook Pro, MacBook Air,'
            ' and Mac mini models. In early 2021, Apple added the M1 iMac'
            'and the M1 iPad Pro. The M1 chip has received rave reviews for'
            'its incredible performance and efficiency.'),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Text('#Development'),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Text('#Management'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    child: Icon(Icons.message),
    onPressed: () {
      print('Button Pressed');
    },
  ),
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Hi Thanks, it worked but actually, I've updated my question could you please have a look and let me know how I can achieve the following design. The first Image is a bit broad which I'm unable to achieve and that floating action button too please can you guide me how to achieve the following things.

Comment: @Bhaskar2510 I have update my answer check it, hope its help to you

Comment: Could you please help me with this problem too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72435347/flutter-how-to-call-images-from-api

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok, just remove `Expanded`.

Your code:

```
const Expanded(
      child: Text(
         "Post Title",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
     ))
```

Instead, use this:

```
const Text(
      "Post Title",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 24.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
)
```